# Parse HTTP URL using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

### Problem

I have a long String, with the following format:

```
'{ "method": "POST", "url": "/iot/pipe/", "query": {}, "body": { "d": {"l": 1523737659, "n": "861359030665564", "b": 100, "v": "02.45", "t": 3, "dev": {"vr":7, "ae":1, "at":5, "ad":2, "as":4, "al":60, "tp":60, "tr":3, "tu":"http"://bus.mapit.me/iot/pipe/, "gt":50, "gm":120, "gh":400, "gs":3, "gr":2, "gg":1, "ua":0, "uu":"http"://bus.mapit.me/firmware/, "le":0, "lt":0, "sw":mapit2_v245, "sp":240, "rt":0, "sa":1}}}, "headers": { "host": "node_session_iot", "connection": "close", "content-length": "298", "accept": "*/*", "user-agent": "QUECTEL_MODULE", "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" } }'
```

Which contains URLs inside like in the example bellow:

```
"uu":"http"://bus.mapit.me/firmware/
```

### Objective

My objective is to transform it into the following, using `String.prototype.replace` and Regex (note that the `"` moved from the end of `"http"` to the end of the string):

```
"uu":"http://bus.mapit.me/firmware/"
```

### What I tried

To achieve this I searched several SO posts and I arrived to the following code, which is not working:

```
str.replace(/\"http\":(\w+)/g, "\"http:$1\"");
```

This does nothing to the string in question. 
My closest match was the follwing:

```
str.replace(/\"http\":/g, "\"http:\"");
```

Which is not exactly useful as all it does is to move a `\"` to the next position, instead of moving it to the end.

### Question

What is wrong in my Regex?

Comment: Note that `"http://foo"` has slash characters which are not part of `\w`. You should at least change it to `/\"http\":\/\/(\w+)/g`, but this will only match your domain, i.e. the first part of your url up to the next `/`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is a great resource for many regular expression related problems.

Comment: @PeterB I want a new string. This is intended!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the regex does not match the given URL. In particular `\w+`in the capturing group means to match one or more word characters, where a word character is any character from the set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. This will not match the forward slashes in the URL because they are not considered to be word characters.

Instead you could use `\S+` to match any sequence of non-whitespace characters. Also, assign the result back to `str` (or another variable) if you need to use it more than once.

```
str = '"uu":"http"://bus.mapit.me/firmware/';
new_str = str.replace(/\"http\":(\S+)/g, "\"http:$1\"");
console.log(new_str);
```

Output:

```
"uu":"http://bus.mapit.me/firmware/"
```

You can try it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/pCkM0U/1).

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```js
var str = '{ "method": "POST", "url": "/iot/pipe/", "query": {}, "body": { "d": {"l": 1523737659, "n": "861359030665564", "b": 100, "v": "02.45", "t": 3, "dev": {"vr":7, "ae":1, "at":5, "ad":2, "as":4, "al":60, "tp":60, "tr":3, "tu":"http"://bus.mapit.me/iot/pipe/, "gt":50, "gm":120, "gh":400, "gs":3, "gr":2, "gg":1, "ua":0, "uu":"http"://bus.mapit.me/firmware/, "le":0, "lt":0, "sw":mapit2_v245, "sp":240, "rt":0, "sa":1}}}, "headers": { "host": "node_session_iot", "connection": "close", "content-length": "298", "accept": "*/*", "user-agent": "QUECTEL_MODULE", "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" } }';
str = str.replace(/"http"([^,]*)/gm, '"http$1"')
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Downvoting explanation will be welcome, I wnat to know what's wrong with the answer.

Comment: You can try the snippet yourself, it is printing 
`"uu":"http://bus.mapit.me/firmware/"` which I understood is the desired output.

Comment: Your example only work if there is nothing more inside of the source string. As far as you don't know the end, your example is simply wrong. Actually your answer is just guessing ...

Comment: The string "contains URLs", this will match everything after `http` possibly lot of data, however without question update, we don't know how to match url end

Comment: Oh, I understand. I missed that it's not a single string. Changed to work on multiple lines

Comment: Updated the Question to have more info!

Comment: Updated with the new info.